# systemd units disabled when calling systemctl daemon-reload

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I am debugging some embedded system running systemd. The behavior I am observing is that the systemd targets `basic.target`, `local-fs.target` and `multi-user.target` are disabled after I run `systemctl daemon-reload` (as shown by `systemctl list-units --type target --all`).
This causes many systemd units to be disabled, and forces me to reboot the system.

Is there a way to debug this systemd target transition? I already enabled `systemctl log-level debug`, but I still don't understand why the systemd target is changing when I call `systemctl daemon-reload` on this particular system.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a dependency conflict or cycle of some sort. Perhaps you have forgotten to set some early-boot service with a `DefaultDependencies=no`?